# Pendulum Physics/Math CAP contest question?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

A grandfather clock measures time by counting the number
of oscillations of a small-angle pendulum. You take
a grandfather clock that gives the correct time at sea
level (where g = 9.81 m/s
2
) up a mountain and notice
that after two days it is running five minutes behind.
What is the value of the gravitational acceleration up
that mountain?

I tried solving this by using $T = \sqrt{l/g}$ and setting up the difference of the reciprocals times the time (2 days) but I got an answer depended on the length of the pendulum. How do I solve this?

Comment: length of string is always constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: assuming that the length are the same at each elevation you can set up a relationship between the tworld periods like this:
$$\frac{T_2}{T_1}=\frac{\sqrt{g_1}}{\sqrt{g_2}}$$

Comment: ok got it, easy peasy now.